# How use TemplateView with 2 methods (get and post)

Tags: django, forms, django-views

I am trying to use Templateview in Django to render a page with options for both adding to the database and retrieving some info from the database and displaying it. I am basing it on the tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VxOsCKMStuw

**views.py:**

```
class TestView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'app/sensor_name_tmpl.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = SensorForm()
        posts = Sensor.objects.all()

        args = {'form': form, 'posts': posts}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)


    def post(self, request):
        form = SensorForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            text = form.cleaned_data['post']
            form = SensorForm()
            return redirect('sensor_name_tmpl:sensor_name_tmpl')

        args = {'form': form, 'text': text}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^form1/$', views.get_sensor_name, name='GiveSensorName1'),
    #url(r'^form2/$', TestView.as_view(), name='sensor_name_tmpl.html'),
    path('form2/', TestView.as_view(), name='app/sensor_name_tmpl.html'),
    url(r'^nested_admin/', include('nested_admin.urls')),
]
```

**HTML template:**

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script>
            $('#toggle').click(function() {
            $('form').toggle('slow');
            });
        </script>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <title>Hello world!</title>
  </head>


  <body>
    <h3 class="text-success">Add Sensor</h3>
    <br>

<!--    <form style="display:none;" method="post">-->
        <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <table>
                   {{ form1.as_table}}
                </table>
                <div class="mx-sm-2">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </div>

                <br>
                <br>

                <h3 class = "text-success">Add Sensor View</h3>
                <table>
                   {{ form2.as_table}}
                </table>
                  <div class="mx-sm-2">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                  </div>
                <br>
                <br>

                <h3 class="text-success">View Sensors</h3>

                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Sensor ID</th>
                            <th scope="col">Sensor Name</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                <tbody>
                {%for obj in obj%}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{obj.sensor_id}}</td>
                        <td>{{obj.sensor_name}}</td>
<!--                        <th scope="row">1</th>-->
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
                </table>





            </div>
        <div>
    </form>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

The page renders the template but doesn't populate it with either the formfields or the data from the database.

Comment: How are you accessing the context in your HTML? edit your post and add your HTML code

Comment: use `FormView` . replace `TemplateView` with `FormView`

Comment: @NalinDobhal, thank you, realised what was wrong in the HTML template, it works now

Answer (score 1):

Being a beginner Django Developer, I will suggest that it is actually not advisable to use TemplateView class for any kind updating of objects or if your template is having a form. You can read more about this [here](https://www.agiliq.com/blog/2017/12/when-and-how-use-django-templateview/#:%7E:text=Django%20provides%20several%20class%20based%20generic%20views%20to,forms%20and%20does%20creation%20or%20update%20of%20objects.).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the HTML template where form1 and form2 have now been replaced with form and "obj" in the for loop has been replaced with "posts". The template now looks as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script>
            $('#toggle').click(function() {
            $('form').toggle('slow');
            });
        </script>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <title>Hello world!</title>
  </head>


  <body>
    <h3 class="text-success">Add Sensor</h3>
    <br>

<!--    <form style="display:none;" method="post">-->
        <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <table>
                   {{ form.as_table}}
                </table>
                <div class="mx-sm-2">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </div>

                <br>
                <br>

                <h3 class = "text-success">Add Sensor View</h3>
                <table>
                   {{ form.as_table}}
                </table>
                  <div class="mx-sm-2">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                  </div>
                <br>
                <br>

                <h3 class="text-success">View Sensors</h3>

                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Sensor ID</th>
                            <th scope="col">Sensor Name</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                <tbody>
                {%for obj in posts%}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{obj.sensor_id}}</td>
                        <td>{{obj.sensor_name}}</td>
<!--                        <th scope="row">1</th>-->
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
                </table>





            </div>
        <div>
    </form>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```